# Error Initializing OpenSSL module in perl

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, perl-module, pkcs#7

Hi I am a newbie to perl. How to create a pkcs7 signature in perl .Any Example code would be helpful. I tried to use OpenCA::OpenSSL. I got error initializing OpenCA::OpenSSL instance.
Thanks in Advance.......
  My code

```
$openssl = OpenCA::OpenSSL->new(path=>'/usr/bin/openssl');
my $crl=$openssl->issueCrl(
       CAKEY=>'passbook/key.pem',
       CACERT=>'passbook/certificate.pem',
       PASSWD=>'somepass',
       OUTFILE=>'passbook/signature',
       OUTFORM=>'DER',
);
```

The error message i got was

```
Use of uninitialized value $initial_skip in concatenation (.) or string at
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Parse/RecDescent.pm line 3054."
```